# ¿Cómo guardo una fecha random en una variable, y cual es la variable para asignar dicha fecha?

Tags: c++

Necesito urgente realizar eso  no se cual es la variable para poner una fecha que no sea la fecha actual de mi equipo, necesito una fecha cualquiera, con tal de que sea dentro de una variable para las fechas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

C++ ofrece una cabecera para trabajar con tiempo, es la cabecera [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). Entre los objetos disponibles al incluir esa cabecera encontramos [`std::chrono::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) que es un objeto que permite acceder al reloj del sistema.

A este objeto le puedes pedir un [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) que como su nombre indica, es un punto en el tiempo.

Sabido todo eso, para construir un tiempo aleatorio puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Calculas una cantidad aleatoria de tiempo (yo he usado horas).
2. Lo sumas al valor más temprano que el reloj de sistema pueda generar.

```
// Generador de numeros aleatorios
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 generador(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(0, 0x7fffffff);

using reloj = std::chrono::system_clock;
using punto = std::chrono::time_point<reloj>;

// El punto más temprano que soporta este reloj.
const auto inicio = punto{};
// Una cantidad de tiempo aleatoria
const auto fecha = std::chrono::hours(distribucion(generador));

const std::time_t time = reloj::to_time_t(inicio + fecha);
std::cout << "Fecha aleatoria: " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&time), "%F %T.\n");
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFNbttADIXX1ikIBykkOH9tFkFkxbumF2h2BQR2ZmxPoiHV@SlaBDlMz5J7RaFGtpvECxl8Ir/3SKm@P1Ud0mYYjiypLmkDjeUQvUG3Kv5rauuZ@K1i2SHZ/q3kkTTLWGEpgkNLZVU8FrPzc/hmyHjU7EH6KDnjOQB2BiN7sStmIeq6nuZbbX5bZcDr5U538fP19eUVbPaU0uuyqvavE9k1e9eKa6utZLc/U7RMzQr2pZKyvDiBiz9X6@kn08UsBUsb8Kbje7iBDJsWrevwN0TjWtWxeljuO/tEkT92RutM27O4N5m0Gsmy89du1@@e/wUQWC/7MfxKBgL37COCEY/J/qyYKaYQAZNMWLKSWIwy4PFpmYF3hKCQotWoxztGK0w@nBHfIdZGbfFj1C0nH8p3RznctMoXmQh5KO8VYfwTTk4pIreTXu4yLianw8dQnCI0Dcxvc4BDuBrmozyh@xQzpsyVnBi7XH4an9UJzI9v4fj72Q@aC/dpGF7UusNNGE6l/0YtFl/wFQ)</kbd>.